# Filter data from many-to-many relation using propel ORM according to given parameter

Tags: php, orm, propel

Here is my database structure,

```
stu_details
-----------
id INT PK AI
f_name VARCAHR(45)
l_name VARCHAR(45)
dob VARCHAR(45)

subject
----------
id INT PK AI
sub_name VARCHAR(45)
day VARCHAR(45)

subject_has_stu_details(associative table)
-----------------------------------------
id INT PK AI
subject_id INT FK (frm subject table)
stu_details_id INT FK (frm stu_details table)
```

My schema.xml ,

```
<table name="stu_details" idMethod="native" phpName="StuDetails">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="f_name" phpName="FName" type="VARCHAR" size="45" required="true"/>
    <column name="l_name" phpName="LName" type="VARCHAR" size="45" required="true"/>
    <column name="sex" phpName="Sex" type="VARCHAR" size="45" required="true"/>
    <column name="dob" phpName="Dob" type="VARCHAR" size="45" required="true"/>
    <vendor type="mysql">
      <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
  </table>
  <table name="subject" idMethod="native" phpName="Subject">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="sub_name" phpName="SubName" type="VARCHAR" size="45" required="true"/>
    <column name="day" phpName="Day" type="VARCHAR" size="45" required="true"/>
    <column name="time" phpName="Time" type="VARCHAR" size="45" required="true"/>
    <vendor type="mysql">
      <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
  </table>
  <table name="subject_has_stu_details" idMethod="native" phpName="SubjectHasStuDetails">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="subject_id" phpName="SubjectId" type="INTEGER" required="true"/>
    <column name="stu_details_id" phpName="StuDetailsId" type="INTEGER" required="true"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="subject" name="fk_subject_has_stu_details_subject1">
      <reference local="subject_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="stu_details" name="fk_subject_has_stu_details_stu_details1">
      <reference local="stu_details_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <index name="fk_subject_has_stu_details_stu_details1_idx">
      <index-column name="stu_details_id"/>
    </index>
    <index name="fk_subject_has_stu_details_subject1_idx">
      <index-column name="subject_id"/>
    </index>
    <vendor type="mysql">
      <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
  </table>
```

I'm trying to filter subjects which are belongs to each single student passing his or her first name as a parameter.

Here is my code so far ,

```
  public function subjects($nm)
     //$nm - student name parameter passing through this 
    {
    $get_Subs=SubjectQuery::create()->join('Subject.SubjectHasStuDetails')
                ->join('SubjectHasStuDetails.StuDetails')
                ->with('StuDetails')->find();
     foreach($get_Subs as $sbj){
         $sbj->getSubName();
      }
```

By this code I get all the subjects done by all student together.
Any suggestions to filter the subjects according to the given student ??

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer anyhow....

```
$get_Subs_stu = \SubjectQuery::create()
            ->useSubjectHasStuDetailsQuery()
            ->useStuDetailsQuery()
            ->filterByFName($nm)
            ->endUse()
            ->endUse()
            ->find();
```